# Return empty collection from a method

Tags: java, performance, collections, garbage-collection

Is there any memory/performance benefit of using the first method over the second?

First

```
public List<Integer> getList1(List<Integer> data) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Integer element: data) {
        if (element % 2 == 0) {
           list.add(element);
        }
    }
    return list.isEmpty() ? Collections.<Integer>emptyList() : list;
}
```

Second

```
public List<Integer> getList2(List<Integer> data) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Integer element: data) {
        if (element % 2 == 0) {
           list.add(element);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Some might consider this to be a premature optimisation. Your second fragment has less complexity than the first and therefore has a lower maintenance cost.

Comment: There would be a gain if you were able to return an emptyList *before* creating the ArrayList. But in your case it won't make much difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The degree to which any of this matters depends on how often `getList1` is called such that it returns an empty list, of course. But:

The JavaDoc for [`Collections#emptyList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList--) offers insight here:

> Implementation note: **Implementations of this method need not create a separate List object for each call.** Using this method is likely to have comparable cost to using the like-named field. (Unlike this method, the field does not provide type safety.)

So yes, you (may) end up with fewer objects in memory if you use `emptyList` rather than returning a new empty list each time, because `Collections#emptyList` is free to return the *same* `List<Integer>` every time you call it (since it's immutable).

You ***may*** get an unrelated performance improvement as well (at least with Oracle's JVM). In some situations, and I'm not au fait with the details at all, but in some situations Oracle's JVM can initially allocate objects assigned to local variables on the *stack*, only transferring them to the heap if a reference to them survives the termination of the function call. Stack-based allocation is *really* fast and doesn't, of course, suffer from fragmentation. So in the empty list scenario, you not only avoid cluttering memory with empty lists, but you get a speed benefit as well (the JVM doesn't have to copy the empty list you created off the stack into the heap). But again, I don't know whether that JVM optimization necessarily applies to your code.

If the memory optimization is **really** important to your code and you don't want to rely on the stack-allocation thing, with a slight sacrifice to code clarity and a *tiny* runtime cost, you can avoid allocating a list *at all* if you don't need one:

```
public List<Integer> getList1(List<Integer> data) {
    List<Integer> list = null;
    for (Integer element: data) {
        if (element % 2 == 0) {
           if (list == null ) {
             list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
           }
           list.add(element);
        }
    }
    return list == null ? Collections.<Integer>emptyList() : list;
}
```

---

Note, though, that there's an important *semantic* difference. In your first code block, `getList1` is inconsistent: It might return a list the calling code can modify (if it isn't empty), or it might return an immutable list (if it was empty). `getList1` should probably always return a mutable or immutable list, not one sometimes and another other times. If it can be immutable, you should probably use [`Collections#unmodifiableList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-) to get an immutable version of your non-empty list, and return that.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, does this mean that if I call this method twice and store the result in two different variables, they could actually have the same reference ?

Comment: @Dici: Yes. Since the list that `emptyList` returns is *immutable*, `Collections#emptyList` is free to return the same list every time. And in Oracles JDK implementation, calling `Collections.<Integer>emptyList();` twice does indeed return the same reference both times. (It doesn't *have* to, you can't rely on it, but in Oracle's JDK8 in a simple test, it does: http://ideone.com/MGMqSf)

Comment: Thanks T.J Crowder. The javadoc specifies the returned list is immutable, so depending of its use the two methods of the OP might not be equivalent because in one case it can return an immutable list whereas the second method will always return a mutable one.

Comment: @Dici: Indeed, I was *just* about to add that to the answer, in fact.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I misunderstood the OP's point. My bad. Also, when you mention - *I believe Oracle's JVM initially (within reason) allocates objects assigned to local variables on the stack, only transferring them to the heap if a reference to them survives the termination of the function call.*, are you talking about *Escape Analysis*?

Comment: @TheLostMind: Thanks for the term! I'm not au fait with that stuff. Apparently it's a combination of two things: *Scalar Replacement* and *Escape Analysis*: http://www.stefankrause.net/wp/?p=64,  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp09275/index.html I don't know whether the OP's code can be optimized that way (which I should clarify in the answer [now have]). Where's [Marko](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1103872/marko-topolnik) when we need him?! :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Can you tell me from where you found out - *I believe Oracle's JVM initially (within reason) allocates objects assigned to local variables on the stack, only transferring them to the heap if a reference to them survives the termination of the function call* , because Oracle's doc on *Escape analysis* (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis) doesn't mention it. Is it mentioned in one of the links provided in your last comment ? :)

Comment: @TheLostMind: Yes, the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are  returning the `list`  anyway, why the condition? It's just redundant.

Prefer the second way.

And also , See that [`emptyList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList()) method docs

> Implementation note: Implementations of this method **need not create a separate List object for each call.** Using this method is likely to have comparable cost to using the like-named field. (Unlike this method, the field does not provide type safety.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle difference.

If `getList1` returns an empty list, then that list is **immutable**:

```
List<Integer> l1 = getList1();
assertTrue(l1.isEmpty());
l1.add(1); //exception

List<Integer> l2 = getList2();
assertTrue(l2.isEmpty());
l2.add(1); //OK
```

Also:

```
List<Integer> l1a = getList1();
List<Integer> l1b = getList1();
assertTrue(l1a.isEmpty());
assertTrue(l1b.isEmpty());
assertSame(l1a, l1b); //same reference so there is some saving in memory

List<Integer> l2a = getList2();
List<Integer> l2b = getList2();
assertTrue(l2a.isEmpty());
assertTrue(l2b.isEmpty());
assertNotSame(l2a, l2b); //not same reference, two unique lists
```

The two are linked, the shared reference would not work if it were not immutable.